# Instrução para adicionar valor no AX

Tags: assembly

Qual o comando/sintaxe a usar para colocar o valor 55d no registrador AX?

Comment: Não percebo o porque de fechar a pergunta por esse motivo. @luciano inclua o código que tem e explique melhor o que pretende fazer, assim fica difícil ajudar com tão pouca informação.

Comment: @JorgeB. Também não. Por isso editei-a e votei para reabrir.

Comment: Normalmente cada assembly está ligado a uma arquitetura específica (qual é a tua?) e a notação pode ainda variar com o assembler que o vai processar (qual a ferramenta?)

Answer (score 14):

Sem mais informações, eu diria que o quer e a instrução [`MOV`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_addressing_modes.htm):

```
MOV AX, 55d
```